# Android ProgressBar in an each item of a ListView from SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have a ListView populated with numeric values ​​from database .....

Now for each record I would like to display a colored horizontal bar (ie for example, if the value is 90 bar must be wide about 90% of the screen ... and so on all other values​​)

I think there is no need to use a library type aChartEngine to achieve the purpose .....

Have you heard about??
thanks

this is my code to calculate the percentage

```
value = value / total *100;
```

Answer (score 1):

For this you have to use custom list view with adapter. Here's a simple code you can use 
http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're going to have to do is create a custom adapter for your ListView.
Here's a tutorial you can use: http://commonsware.com/Android/excerpt.pdf, scroll down to page 22.

Then you can use a ProgressBar for each view.